# standard model of floating point arithmetic

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

The standard model is:
$$fl(x\; \text{op} \; y)=(x\; \text{op} \; y)(1+\delta),$$ 
where $|\delta| \le \epsilon$, but this ignores the rounding error after the computation.  I had thought that it should have been:
$$fl(x\; \text{op} \; y)=(x(1+\delta_1)\;\text{op}\;y(1+\delta_2))(1+\delta_3),$$ where $|\delta_i| \le \epsilon$.  Could someone clarify?

Comment: You're using nonstandard notation (and probably asking on the wrong forum)... but if I'm guessing the meaning correctly, the thing you seem to have missed is that multiplication by $(1+\delta)$ is *precisely* the correction term expressing the "rounding error after the computation", so it's not ignored at all.

Comment: @Hurkyl The notation is from Higham's "Accuracy and Stability of Numerical Algorithms" where $\delta$ is the relative error and $\epsilon$ is the unit roundoff. The same notation is used by Heath except that he uses $\epsilon$ to mean machine precision. As well, which forum should this be asked on?

Comment: Other sources use other notations. It's a good idea in any case to name the symbols one uses in a question like this, for example "where $\epsilon$ is the unit roundoff" (so that, for example, nobody thinks you meant it to be machine precision).

Comment: I reformated your question, but the only real change I have made to your text is to add absolute value signs around your $\delta$s. Note that Higham does in fact use $u$ to denote the unit roundoff, see page 38 of the 2002 edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Higham's book the standard model for floating point arithmetic is written as
$$ \text{fl}(x\,\text{op}\, y) = (x\, \text{op}\, y)(1+\delta),$$
where $x, y \in \mathcal{F}$ are machine numbers and $|\delta| \leq u$, where $u$ is the unit round off.

If $x$ and $y$ are real numbers in the representable range, then
$$ \text{fl}(x) = x(1+\delta_x), \quad \text{fl(y)} = y(1 + \delta_y),$$
where $|\delta_x|, |\delta_y| \leq u$.

When seeking to compute $s=x+y$ where $x$ and $y$ are real numbers, the best we can hope for is
$$ \hat{s} = \text{fl}(\text{fl}(x) + \text{fl}(y)) = \left[x(1+\delta_x) + y(1+\delta_y)\right](1+\delta).$$
This is the expression which you felt should replace the standard model. You simply missed that the standard model refers to machine numbers, rather than real numbers.

---

The unit roundoff $u$ is also known as machine precision. It should not be confused with machine epsilon, i.e. the distance between 1 and the next floating point number. In base $\beta$ and precision $t$, machine epsilon is
$$ \epsilon_M = \beta^{1-t}.$$
If we use round to nearest, then
$$ u = \frac{1}{2} \epsilon_M.$$
If we use directed rounding, then
$$ u = \epsilon_M.$$

Answer (score 3):

In a formulation of the standard model of floating point arithmetic,
generally we start with two operands $x$ and $y,$
which are the values *received by the processor* on which to perform the desired operation.

It is also very often true that in the larger context of calculations in which one such operation occurs, the input operands $x$ and $y$ are themselves the result of some previous calculations--even if the calculations are only the conversion from data entered in decimal format to the internal binary floating-point format of the computer.

As a result of those previous calculations, it is possible that neither $x$ nor $y$ is equal to the value that it would have in a perfectly accurate computation. But any such difference is accounted for in the application of the model to earlier operations.
Note that once a number is output by one operation, it is already in the
floating-point format of the computer (having been rounded as needed during that operation) and does not require any additional rounding before being used as input to another operation.

The error of $x$ or $y$ (relative to their "true" values) can indeed be *much greater* than the rounding error of the floating-point representation, due to accumulated errors (of all kinds, not just rounding errors) from multiple previous operations. So your proposed model not only overcounts the errors according to the usual way of accounting for things,
it *underestimates* the possible error if it is supposed to represent the possible difference between the $x$ and $y$ the operation receives and the 
$x$ and $y$ the operation "should" receive.

Comment: In addition to simple accumulation of rounding errors, one might want to mention the effects of subtractive cancellation and of error magnification (e.g. when computing $exp(x)$).

Comment: I was trying to account for other effects by writing "accumulated errors" rather than "accumulated rounding errors," but now I see that that was ambiguous. I did not want to try to make a complete list (I would almost surely fail at that), but I have edited the last paragraph in an attempt to make it clear that not only rounding may be involved.

Comment: "the standard model of computer arithmetics",  presented in this question, assumes, that operands $x$, $y$ are exact, so it cannot underestimate  error due to inaccuracy of inputs. What is "the usual way of counting things" in case of roundoff error analysis?

Comment: The usual way of counting thing is the way I described in the middle two paragraphs. But I am working at a disadvantage here, because I can only guess why you think your extra $(1+\delta_i)$ factors are necessary. Why don't you edit the question so it explains the reason for those factors?

Answer (score 2):

This model of computation assumes that:

1. Floating point operands $x$, $y$ are exact, i.e. $\text{fl}(x) = x$ and $\text{fl}(y) = y$.
2. Computation of $z \equiv x\ \text{op} \ y $ for $\text{op} = $ $+$, $-$, $*$, $/$ is exact, is performed with infinite accuracy.
3. The only source of error is the roundoff error $\text{fl}(z)$. This error cannot be avoided, since usually $z$ cannot be represented by floating point number.

This notation however can be quite confusing. To be more explicit let define by $\tilde{\text{op}}$ the result of operation $\text{op}$ returned by a computer. If this model is satisfied, then $x \ \tilde{\text{op}} \ y $ must be equal to $\text{fl}(x\ \text{op} \ y)$ and 
$$x \ \tilde{\text{op}} \ y \doteq \text{fl}(x\ \text{op} \ y) = (x\ \text{op}\ y)\times (1+\delta), \ \ |\delta| \leq \varepsilon$$
where $\varepsilon$ is the machine epsilon.

This model is valid on computers, that implements IEEE 784 standard of floating point computation with some differences:

1. This model is not valid, when overflow or underflow occures, i.e. when $|z| > \text{MAX}$, or $|z| < \text{MIN}$, where $\text{MAX}$ is the largest representable number and $\text{MIN}$ is the smallest positive nonzero representable number.
2. Computation error is much larger, when $x$, $y$, or $z$ is so called denormal number, i.e. small nonzero number, that cannot be represented with full accuracy possible for (normal) floating point numbers of given type.
3. For default rounding mode (i.e. round to nearest ties to even) actual accuracy is 
   $\text{fl}(x\ \text{op} \ y) = (x\ \text{op}\ y)\times (1+\delta)$ for $|\delta| \leq \frac{1}{2}\varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon$ is the machine epsilon.
4. For fused operations, $x \pm y\times z$, computed result can be much more accurate than predicted by this model.

Comment: @littleO Yes, this model is valid for IEE 784 floats. Notice, that a computer need not behaves exactly as this model requires. It is enough to produce the same result. IEE 784 floats behaves as if operations are performed with full accuracy. It is assumed, that $x$, $y$ are exact, i.e. significants can be represented using only 53 bits.  Then result of multiplication and addition requires 106 bits for exact representation. Then result should be rounded. It is possible to perform equivalent computations with much lower internal precision.

Comment: Nitpick; fused multiply and add should be covered by the same model, just with a ternary operation rather than a binary one.